# Are there elegant ways to turn a List into a NonEmptyList in kotlin and arrow?

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 

    if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
        Nel(list[0], list.subList(1, list.lastIndex))
    }
}
```

According to arrow documents, it seems be able to do it through `Semigroup` or `Monad binding`. 
However, there is no code to replace `List` with `NonEmptyList`.

Is there a better way to replace `List` with`NonEmptyList` without using `subList`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a companion function [`fromList`](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/blob/master/modules/core/arrow-extras/src/main/kotlin/arrow/data/NonEmptyList.kt#L91) that return an `Option<NonEmptyList>` or if you are sure use `fromListUnsafe`:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

val nelistOption = NonEmptyList.fromList(list)

val nelist = NonEmptyList.fromListUnsafe(list)
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrow 1.1.3 has introduced a more Koltin idiomatic way to achieve this with the introduction of [Iterable.toNonEmptyListOrNull(): NonEmptyList?](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core/arrow.core/index.html#1502078066%2FFunctions%2F1495421781)

Example:

```kotlin
val list: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val nonEmptyList: NonEmptyList<Int>? = list.toNonEmptyListOrNull()
```

To get the old `Option` type one can use the `toOption()` extension function

```kotlin
val list: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val nonEmptyList: Option<NonEmptyList<Int>> = list.toNonEmptyListOrNull().toOption()
```

or use Option.fromNullable()

```kotlin
val list: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val nonEmptyList: Option<NonEmptyList<Int>> = Option.fromNullable(list.toNonEmptyListOrNull())
```

The NonEmptyList.fromList() function is now deprecated in favor of toNonEmptyListOrNull.

Comment: There is also `fun A?.toOption(): Option<A>` if you'd prefer that over `Option.fromNullable`.

Comment: Yeah very good point, I'll add it to my answer.
Maybe the @Deprecated function inside arrow.core can also be updated to use this instead of the Option.fromNullable, what do you think? I suggested this initially since it's the one that was auto-fixed by the IDE with the way the deprecated annotation was setup in the library.

Comment: Oh, great point! Yes, lets update that!